# Managing Bitlocker encryption on C#

Tags: c#, bitlocker

I need to manage (short for "enable and then immediately disable") bitlocker encryption on removable drives.

Bitlocker is enforced by company policy, but in order to release to customers their USB installation drives I need to encrypt the drives, move the needed files into themand finally decrypt them. This takes a lot of time and is currently manually made, so I would love to automate the crypt/copy/decrypt part and integrate it into my C# solution.

I tried to write a Powershell scrip (disclaimer: I don't know how to script in PS) but I keep getting errors like this:

```
Enable-BitLocker : Impossibile risolvere il set di parametri utilizzando i parametri denominati specificati.
In C:\Projects\Selco.WeldNet.SinergyManager\Selco.Weldnet.SynergyManager.LicenseCreator\Script\ManageUSBDrive.ps1:49 car:2
+     Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint "$thisDriveletter" -EncryptionMethod ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Enable-BitLocker], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Enable-BitLocker
```

Aren't any api/library/nuget package for C# that could help managing bitlocker?